# Android keyboard input weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I notice Android devices' default keyboard behave in a different ways, but I have 1 particular behaviour that I am unsure what it is and how to configure the keyboards settings. See the info below.

1. When Click in any edittext to get focus, the Keyboard shows up
2. When I type "Hello", the edittext don't get filled with the text immediately. I need to click the suggested "Hello" and then the text shows up in the edittext

Questions:

1. What are the settings to make the keyboard behave this way?
2. Is this behaviour the same on all Android keyboards? (I think no but, I
   don't find any supporting references)
3. Do you guys know any 3rd party keyboard app that has this feature?
4. How to know if the user is using this type of keyboard?

To detect user interaction I use a combination of (1)onUserInteraction() and a (2)custom TextWatcher implementation. Both are tested and working so I didn't add the source codes. I mentioned the 2 above because those kind of **keyboards** with that behavior textchanges cannot be detected.

[image]

From the screenshots above "Hello" will only show when you click the green "Hello" in the left screenshot.

Comment: post some code (your textwatcher for example)

Comment: Hi @A.A there is no problem with the textwatcher implementation so I didn't add. I updated the post!